# .htaccess rules for a particular type of URL

Tags: .htaccess

Could you please help to get this work -

```
http://domain.com/gallery/category/another/slug
```

to

```
http://domain.com/gallery/
```

If URL contains word `gallery` and no matter what's the rest of part it will always send request to `http://domain.com/gallery/`

```
http://domain.com/gallery/category/another/slug -> will hit http://domain.com/gallery/
http://domain.com/gallery/another/slug -> will hit http://domain.com/gallery/
http://domain.com/gallery/more/more/slug -> will hit http://domain.com/gallery/
```

Currently my existing .htaccess looks like this -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want every gallery URL to rewrite to `/gallery/` you can just do

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/.* /gallery/
```

That will look for any URL at your hostname whose path starts with (`^`) the word `gallery` and is followed by anything (`.*`) and rewrite it as `/gallery/`

You can add a couple of flags -- `[L]` if you want to stop evaluating other rules, `[NC]` if it should not be case sensitive.

You might need to play around with the order if you're adding this to a bunch of existing rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can see my current .htaccess file. I have added `RewriteRule ^gallery/.* /gallery/ [L]` before line `RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]` it's showing Object not found! if i add `RewriteRule ^gallery/.* /site/gallery/ [L]` it shows internal server error. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: does <http://domain.com/gallery/> exist? Also, the `[L]` indicates that this should be the last rule executed. That may or may not be what you want. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html or https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html for details

Comment: yes domain.com/gallery exists, i just want to show domain.com/gallery page content if user hit domain.com/gallery or domain.com/gallery/more or domain.com/gallery/more/slug

Comment: When you say "it shows" or "it's showing" do you mean the browser?  Does the URL change?

Comment: No URL didn't changed. Also I don't want to change in url either

Comment: I did some tinkering with this and it definitely works for me, so a couple of additional suggestions: First, take a look at your error logs. They might offer some insights. Second, this might be made more complicated by WordPress and you might consider asking a Wordpress question and being clear about what you're trying to accomplish. There might be a method that doesn't involve `.htaccess` at all that's more reliable.